# Why is query ask for parameter value?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I wrote the SQL code for MS Access.

**All the values except for 12345 are text (VARCHAR).**

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
VALUES (12345, 'Mary', 'Jones', '123 George St', 'Canberra', 'ACT', '1000', '0298754689')
```

and when i execute it, it is asking for parameter for all the text fields.

How do I have to overcome this?

Thank you

Comment: How many parameters are there, Are you sure you are supplying values for all the parameters.

Comment: 9 parameters in total but I only need to insert for 8 parameter.
But my last parameter is also NOT NULL

Comment: The syntax with which you are inserting will expects 9 values(All) and you are passing only 8 so it results an error

Answer (score 3):

What is exactly the error message?

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
VALUES (12345, 'Mary', 'Jones', '123 George St', 'Canberra', 'ACT', '1000', '0298754689')
```

Only executes successfully if the number of values you provided is equal to number of fields in the table, you may not indicate the field names.

But if your number of values is not equal to the number of fields on your table then you have to specify to which specific fieldname you want the values to be put into.

```
INSERT INTO table (field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8)
VALUES (12345, 'Mary', 'Jones', '123 George St', 'Canberra', 'ACT', '1000', '0298754689')
```

if you have 9 fields and you dont want to include the 9th field then set it to NULL or if your 9th field presumably a unique number then set it to autoincrement and you dont have to put the field names.

Comment: +1 Agreed, and they must be in the proper order as well. However, I reckon that it is safer to always include field (column) names.

Comment: safer in a way you know where the values are going into but if you are sure with the order of fields then you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Fields Name missing in your query.

```
Insert into <TableName> (Fieldsname)
Values (values)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify your columns' names on the query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2, clo3, .., col8)VALUES 
(12345, 'Mary', 'Jones', '123 George St', 'Canberra', 'ACT', '1000', '0298754689')
```

Comment: No, you do not. As long as the number of values is equal to the number of columns and the values are in the correct order, the query will work.

Answer (score 0):

Small change required in your insert statement as you are inserting only 8 values. and there are 9 values in your table.

on a assumption that you are not inserting value into last column in your table than statement should be like this

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
VALUES (12345, 'Mary', 'Jones', '123 George St', 'Canberra', 'ACT', '1000', '0298754689',null)
```

if it is the first column than

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
VALUES (null,12345, 'Mary', 'Jones', '123 George St', 'Canberra', 'ACT', '1000', '0298754689')
```

Simply place null at nth position where you are not inserting for example it is 3 column than

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
VALUES (12345, 'Mary', null, 'Jones', '123 George St', 'Canberra', 'ACT', '1000', '0298754689')
```